# jsp quotes inside quotes inside quotes can't figure how to escape this

Tags: jsp, quotes

Hey I can't figure out how I should escape this. "/" doesn't seem to work. Any help ?

```
<c:out value="<a href='<c:url value="threads.jsp">
    <c:param name="idSub" value="${subforum.idsubforum }"/>
    <c:param name="subName" value="${subforum.name }"/>
</c:url>'>${subforum.name}
</a>" escapeXml=""/>
```

Comment: What are you doing with `value="<a href='<c:url value="threads.jsp"`?

Comment: I'm trying to get the id of the forum an user want to see the threads in. So i use the <c:url> tag to put parameters in it. Then when the user get on the threads.jsp page it scans my bdd for the thread that have the same id as the one I sent in the parameter.

Comment: What is the need of `<c:out>` here? Instead, you should be able to do it like - `<c:url var="link" value="threads.jsp"><c:param name="idSub" value="${subforum.idsubforum }"/><c:param name="subName" value="${subforum.name }"/></c:url>` and then `<c:url>` can be referenced in `<a>` just like `<a href="${link}">${subforum.name}</a>`. There is no need to use `<c:out>` in this case.

Comment: My EL expressions are not working unless I use <c:out>. I did it and the result is my links look like this : ${subforum.name}  instead of the name of the subforum.

Comment: Although this is legal and should work - `<a href="${link}">${subforum.name}</a>`, try replacing it by `<a href="${link}"><c:out value="${subforum.name}"/></a>`.

Comment: this is working thanks a lot. Gonna I give you + rep if I find how to.

Comment: To whom who could have this issue in the future. I was using a Jboss 7 which I think use a bad version of JSTL. So upgrade your server.